# Angular2 - Trying to add a component into a child component from parent

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add component dynamically into a child component from the parent component. I have injected the child component so that I can call its method in order to add component into the child component. Here is how I am doing it:

**test.ts**

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader,ElementRef,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ChildComponent} from './child_test.ts';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: '<div #element></div>',
    providers: [ChildComponent,ElementRef]
})
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    constructor(private _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _childComponent: ChildComponent) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'element');
        this._childComponent.addElement();
    }

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**child_test.ts**

```
import {Component, ElementRef,DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'element',
    template: '<div>Test Element</div>'
})
export class MyElement{}



@Component({
    selector: "child-component",
    template: "<div>Child Component</div>"
})
export class ChildComponent{

    constructor(public _elementRef: ElementRef,private _loader: DynamicComponentLoader){}
    public addElement(){
        this._loader.loadNextToLocation(MyElement,this._elementRef);
    }
};
```

When execute the test.ts I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getViewContainerRef' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question but I think this is what you want

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this._loader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent,this._elementRef,'element')
    .then(childComponent => childComponent.instance.addElement());
}
```

`this._loader.loadIntoLocation(...)` returns a `Promise` that completes with a reference to the added element.

Comment: Now I am getting the following error "EXCEPTION: TypeError: childComponent.addElement is not a function"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `.instance` (updated my answer). You also shouldn't add ` providers: [ChildComponent,ElementRef]` See https://plnkr.co/edit/sWwn1zauMVG709RUpGZf?p=preview for the full example.